# httpOnly flag not working in CDbHttpSession in Yii Framework

Tags: php, session, cookies, yii, cdbhttpsession

I'm trying to raise the flag of '`httpOnly`' for '`cookieParams`' property in '`CDbHttpSession`' for session configurations. As described in [`Yii Documentation`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#cookieParams-detail)
This flag is somehow not working and `document.cookie` in javascript is always able to show the cookie value.

Here is my array in main config:

```
'session'=>array(
            'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
            'connectionID'=>'db', 
            'sessionTableName' => 'yiisession',
            'sessionName' => 'session_name',
            'timeout' => 24 * 3600,
            'autoStart'=>false,
            'cookieParams' => array(
                           'httpOnly'=>true,
                     ),
        ),
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here ?

Thank you

Comment: Try httponly in lowercase.

Comment: @sam dark tried already.

Comment: @SamDark Sorry my bad, you were right. I was doing a mistake. Yes, It was a lower case problem. Could you please answer it below so I may accept it as right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the flag to be applied you need to specify it as the following:

```
'session'=>array(
    'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',

    // ...

    'cookieParams' => array(
        'httponly' => true, // note that "O" is lowercase
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Also protect csrf cookie

```
'request'=>array(
    // ...

    'csrfCookie' => array(
        'httpOnly' => true,
    ),
),
```